# Error about inherit master page in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: master-page, inheritance, team-sites

I've created a site collection at :

- mycompany.net(publishing portal template)

Then I've created 2 sub sites:

- mycompany.net/team(using team site template)
- mycompany.net/learn(using enterprise template)

After setting my custom .master for mycompany.net, the Learn Site inherited this custom MasterPage, but the Team Site doesn't. I noticed that by default we can't create the Team Site as a sub site of mycompany.net because it's using the publishing portal template. I've modified the "Pagelayout and site template" setting to add Team Site to the list sub site of mycompany.net" .

Answer (score 0):

For the Sub Sites to inherit the master page automatically, you will need to activate "**SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure**"site collection feature and then activate  "**SharePoint Server Publishing**" site feature in the sub site.

Now in your case since your Top level root site is having publishing portal template, the **SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure** site collection feature is activated by default.

Also when you created, sub site using Enterprise template the **SharePoint Server Publishing** is activated by default while sub site creation, but this is not activated by default for team site template sites. So you will have to activate that feature in your team sub site.

Comment: I've activated it already :) . Even I set MyCustomMasterPage for this site, it still didn't effect. That wierd.